# not able to access website using website url ( localhost: port works )

Tags: apache, ubuntu, web, virtualbox

I have the following configuration:

Host : Windows7

virtualization software : VirtualBox

Guest : Ubuntu 15.10 32-bit

apache ver : Apache/2.4.12 (Ubuntu)

have the following conf for the website : ([Orignal](https://bhou.wordpress.com/2011/11/28/how-to-install-and-configure-mod_python-in-apache-2-server/)  )

```
  <VirtualHost *:8888>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  ServerName testSite.com
  ServerAlias www.testSite.com
  DocumentRoot /srv/www/testSite.com/web/
  ErrorLog /srv/www/testSite.com/logs/error.log
  CustomLog /srv/www/testSite.com/logs/access.log combined

 <Directory /srv/www/testSite.com/web/>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride None
      Order allow,deny
      allow from all
      Require all granted
      AddHandler mod_python .py
      PythonHandler mod_python.publisher
      PythonDebug On
 </Directory>
```

Now when I access :

```
    127.0.0.1:8888
```

I am able to access the webpage. But when I try :

```
  http://testSite.com/index.html
```

It doesn't works

I thought , this is some redirection problem so, I changed the /etc/hosts to the following

```
  127.0.0.1     testSite.com
```

Still it doesn't works.

Kindly suggest as what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are Listening to a non-standard port number i.e. 8888, this port number must be added to all urls.

So you have to use

```
http://testSite.com:8888/index.html
```

Additional Note:

You also have mixed Apache 2.2 and Apache 2.4 access syntax in here So as you are using Apache 2.4 you can remove the Apache 2.2 syntax, see commented out lines.

```
<Directory /srv/www/testSite.com/web/>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride None
#     Order allow,deny
#     allow from all
      Require all granted
      AddHandler mod_python .py
      PythonHandler mod_python.publisher
      PythonDebug On
 </Directory>
```